# Windows XP install driver notification for AirCard

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, installation, network-adapter, aircard

A co-worker of mine is using an air-card.  It prompted him to install software in the notification tray, but he clicked on the wrong thing and the icon went away without him installing that software.  How can I get that icon back?  He can't install the software then.  I know that you can download the software from the site, but we did that and were having issues from that too.

Restarting and trying again doesn't pop up the notification either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Device Manager and see if it shows up as an unknown device. If so, right click it and select the option to update the driver from the context menu.